# How can we cache the result of gethostbyname?

Tags: c, gethostbyname

My proxy server is spending a lot of time resolving the domain names,is there a way to make `gethostbyname` cache the result?

Comment: Slightly tangential, but `gethostbyname` is an obsolete function you should not be using. `man getaddrinfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nscd, the [name serivce caching daemon](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd)

Comment: do you mean that after this service is up,subsequent calls by `gethostbyname` will automatically be cached?

Comment: This is exactly what it does. Just have a look at the man page. Caching of negative and positive results can be configured separatley, AFAIK

Comment: Sounds like a silly system-specific approach to doing something that could just as easily be accomplished with a caching/proxy nameserver on localhost...

Comment: Wrong point of view. A caching name server is the heavyweight approach to do something which can be easily accomplished by nscd :-) nscd does does have a slightly different scope, as it does cache `getpwnam()` and `getgrpnam()`. Very effective in avoiding heavy brain damage if you are on a network with a lagging NIS server.